# Make PDF file with Laravel DomPDF

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf

When i use laravel DomPDF customization pdf template but i use  structure bootstrap and use css property box-shadow like this.

```
box-shadow: 0 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
```

Error display in domPDF

```
'box_shadow' is not a valid CSS2 property.
```

Please help me

Comment: `box_shadow` is almost certainly a CSS3 feature. Not a CSS2 property. At the very least there is no guarantee that because something is valid CSS2 that a PDF engine that tries to support html/css to PDF will do so for all rules it claims it supports or render the CSS consistently with how a web browser would.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a warning for a known validator bug (see other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900245/css3-box-shadow-property-doesnt-validate)).

The warnings are on by default in debug mode, but will be off in production.
If you want to hide them, read the [domPDF manual](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) and turn it off by using:

```
PDF::loadHTML($html)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->setWarnings(false)->save('myfile.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
media="print"
```

in bootstrap cdn like

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```